# Adding Class to jQuery Colorbox Wrapper Breaks CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, plugins, colorbox

I'm developing a jQuery plugin called PIFF (PDF Inline Formatting Function).  It makes any link you want that goes to a PDF open in a nice window with a reader so you don't have to download it.  I want it so each link can have its own theme but when I add a class to to the parent element, the CSS gets effed in the ay.  I have forked a slightly altered copy of my working version ( <s>http://nsra.tv2media.com/piff/</s> ) for you all to check: <s>http://nsra.tv2media.com/piffcopy/</s>.  I am merely doing `$("#colorbox").addClass("THEME NAME")` and making all the appropriate colorbox CSS selectors children of that class, but alas.  Thank you.

**EDIT:** If you'd like, you can try your hand at solving my problem by checking out the GitHub repo at https://github.com/terrasoftlabs/piff

Comment: The example links lead me to a 404.  I guess that is the place the debug, or maybe it means you've solved the problem :)

Comment: I've given up on the idea for now.  You can download it through GitHub now however as a jQuery plugin.  Check the new links.

Answer (score 0):

You may be experiencing this because you are altering the width or height of the colorbox by either using margin, padding, width, height, top, bottom, left, right, etc. The width and height of the colorbox are set before cbox_open is fired. So even if you add the class via the cbox_open event, the size of the colorbox will already be set via Javascript based on what CSS was previously there.